# access table.subtable value dynamically

Tags: dynamic, lua, lua-table

Im trying to access a subtable value in a dynamical way, but I can't find a proper/smart way to do this. Here is an example code of what I want to achieve:

```
local var = "mySubTable1" --this value is different every time

local myTable = {
    mySubTable1 = {"hello","world","goodbye","city"},
    mySubTable2 = {"this", "is", "a", "test"},
    ...
}

print(myTable.var[3]) --I know this doesnt work, but how can I fix this?
```

Comment: `myTable[var][3]` is the right way `a.b` is the same as for `a["b"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table is indexed by a key like this:

```
myTable[expression_that_evaluates_to_the_key]
```

If the key is a string and happens to be a valid Lua identifier then this syntactic sugar can be used:

```
myTable.mySubTable1
```

You already knew that shortcut. Just go back to the fundamentals:

```
print(myTable[var][3])
```